# Docker PHP application container - unable to connect to mysql container with database hosted outside the container

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I have a PHP application in a docker container and running mysql in a different container with its database hosted outside the container. Used volumes to make that connection. 
Now, the existing database has defined users. I am looking to connect my PHP application container to connect to the database container and use the existing user id defined in the database to run the application. 
Both the containers are up and running,however the PHP code is not able to connect to mysql. Can someone help me please.

```
Docker-compose.yml:

version: '3'
services:
     db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
     qa_api_test:
        build:
          context: ./
        ports:
          - "80:80"
        depends_on:
          - db
```

---

```
Docker file:
   FROM php:7.2-apache-buster
   WORKDIR /var/www/sites/test
   COPY . /var/www/sites/test
   RUN apt-get update && \
      docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
      apt-get clean && \
      apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends && rm -rf 
      /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  RUN printf "\n" | pecl install imagick
  RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick
  RUN a2enmod rewrite
  COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

---

```
Error: From postman:
```

**Warning**:  mysqli: :__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in **/var/www/sites/test/inc/test6.inc.php** on line **30**

**Warning**:  mysqli: :set_charset(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **/var/www/sites/test/inc/test6.inc.php** on line **31**

**Warning**:  mysqli: :real_escape_string(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **/var/www/sites/test/inc/test6.inc.php** on line **226**

**Warning**:  mysqli: :query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **/var/www/sites/test/inc/test6.inc.php** on line **54**

**Warning**:  ExecFetchObj(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **/var/www/sites/test/inc/test6.inc.php** on line **57**

**Warning**:  ExecFetchObj(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in **/var/www/sites/test/inc/test6.inc.php** on line **57**

```
PHP Code:
    function SqlDbConnect($baseName, $user, $passWord, $host, 
&$sqlError)
        { 
            global $CnxLst, $CnxDbLst;

                $key = $host."-".$baseName;
                if ((! isset($CnxLst[$key])) || (! $CnxLst[$key]))
                {
            $CnxLst[$key] = new mysqli($host, $user, $passWord, 
$baseName);
            $CnxLst[$key]->set_charset("utf8mb4");
                        if ($CnxLst[$key] === false)
                        {
                                $sqlError = "ERROR: Failed to connect 
to MySQL Server $host/$baseName [".mysqli_connect_errno().': 
'.mysqli_connect_error().']';
                                if (DBDEBUG) logDebug::log($sqlError); 
                                return false;
                        }
                        $CnxDbLst[$key] = '';
                }
                // logDebug::log("SqlDbConnect($baseName, $user, 
$passWord, $host) => CnxLst[$key] set");
                return $CnxLst[$key];
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: Updated the error messages i see from Postman

Comment: Hello GAN, can you format your PHP code correctly ? It more pleasant for other user to read a good formatted text. Can you explain when you debug first error. You give line number of your code, but, for me, it is impossible to know line number in what you have posted. Can you be more clear. Don't give error's messages that occurs on other lines; only error's message on first line with error is important.